# Google Analytics core API - External sources of data

Tags: php, google-analytics, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I have been exploring some with the Google Analytics Core API. I reached the point where I wish to collect queries from external/other sources. Yes, I do know for some people this may sound a bit stupid, since this is very sensitive data for some companies or whatever. Anyhow, is this possible? Is it some kind of identification that can be found in the dashboard of Google API:s? That lets others to get access of the same data, but from other API requests?

I have tried other webpages view ID:s but without success.

I can not find any documentation about this matter either.

This is possible on the Adobe Analytics API. So I see no reason why it shouldnt be able to do on Google Analytics?

**Edited, scenario added.**

> Im trying to figure out how many sessions a website for which I do not
>   own has.

I want access of the data in google analytics that my company has. I'm wondering if this is possible to get their data from my API requests based on their identifications,etc. I want to create my own dashboard with many different Google analytics sources. Or, do I need to use the same client_secrets that is connected in the Google API dashboard of the owners?

Kind regards, Peter

Comment: It is not exactly clear from your question what you are trying to do. Are you trying to share your data publicly like in the [server side auth demo](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/)? Or are you trying to join your data with other information to create a [dashboard](datastudio.google.com)? Or are you trying to figure out how many sessions a website for which you do not own has had? Or are you trying to create an app and let other's see their own data, ie  [OAuth](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v4/authorization)

Comment: Thank you Matt, I added a scenario. Hopefully this helps :)

-Peter

Answer (score 0):

You should understand the difference between private and public data.  Private data is owned by a user public data is owned by no one.   Searching for public videows on YouTube would be a good example of public data.

Google Analytics data is private it is owned by the person or people who have access to that Google analytics account.   You can not access the data associated with my website unless I grant you access to it.   If you are working on an application and need to access someone else's Google analytics data then you can use Oauth2 (using client id and secret) and have them authenticate the application and you will be able to access their data.

You can not access Google Analytics data that you do not have permission to access.  We get permission by using Oauth2 or a service account.

If you have been added to your companies google analytics account and you have access to it then you can use the Google Analytics API to access the data for those accounts.   By going though the [management api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/accountSummaries/list) you will be able to see all of the accounts that you have access to and use that to make your dashboard.

Just remember though the Google Analytics api returns raw data not graphs you will have to create your dashboard yourself.  or try checking out the [embedded api](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/) but that will only work with one view at a time i as far as i know.